# Como configurar PHP en Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, vscode

He intentado las configuraciones siguiendo tutoriales y blog y persiste el error de PHP no found. Leí alguna respuesta de acá y tampoco me ha resultado.
Alguien sabría ayudarme?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Auqnue no lo creas, para que te puedan ayudar, deberias decir TODO lo que probaste, porque si te dan las mismas configuraciones que ya probaste, vamos a terminar en circulos.

Comment: Agrega la ruta donde está el ejecutable de PHP, por ejemplo `C:\Xampp\php` a la [variable de entorno](https://www.google.com/search?q=agregar+variable+de+entorno+path) `PATH` **de sistema**. Cuando vuelvas a abrir el VSCode va a jalar el PHP automaticamente.

Comment: Lo intenté pero no lo realizaba, Debí desinstalar el VSCode por completo e instalarlo desde cero. Ahí fue que tomó la ruta del ejecutable. Muchas gracias